# class-transfrom @Transform execute twice and return null

Tags: nestjs, class-transformer

I use nestjs and class-transfrom to serialize the return value. But ran into this problem:

Here is the code picture
￼
[image]
￼

￼[image]
[image]

question:

It is printed twice in @Transfrom, but the value is missing when it returns the second time.

￼[image]

Comment: it maybe caused by thid code`app.useGlobalInterceptors(new ClassSerializerInterceptor(app.get(Reflector)));`

Comment: did you managed to fix it? if yes, do you remember how?